# Datetimepicker size in datagridview

Tags: .net, datagridview, datetimepicker

I am trying to add Datetimepicker control to a datagridview, the code I am using working just fine, the only issue is when I change the row height from 25 to 35 on design time, the datetimepicker doesn't resize to fit the whole cell.

[image]

Here is the code I am using on cell click event:

```
 Dim oRectangle As Rectangle = DataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, True)
' Setting area for dateTimePicker1.
 DateTimePicker1.Size = New Size(oRectangle.Width, oRectangle.Height)
' Setting location for dateTimePicker1.
 DateTimePicker1.Location = New Point(oRectangle.X, oRectangle.Y)
```

What can I try to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Okay

the unique way I found is to change the datetimepicker Font size

the height of the DateTimepicker is not sizable.. unless you change the font size